# Why did javascript stop working when I implemented ZF2 ACL?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I am using Bootstrap with my Zend Framework 2 app. The formatting was looking good until I implemented ACL controls. Now the only time the buttons are formatted is when the user's role is guest. Any ideas on what went wrong?

@Zend Framework2 folks: Is there any need to include the css and js files in the ACL list?

The ACL control from config/autoload/acl.global.php looks like:

```
return array(
  'acl' => array(
    'roles' => array(
      'guest'   => null,
      'member'  => 'guest',
      'mentor' => 'member',
      'board' => 'mentor',
      'admin'  => 'board',
    ),
  'resources' => array(
    'allow' => array(
      'Register\Controller\Profile' => array(
        'index' => 'guest',
        'confirm' => 'member',
        'process' => 'guest',
        'edit' => 'member',
        'saveEdit' => 'member',
        'family' => 'member',
        'delete' => 'member',
      ),
      'Register\Controller\Index' => array(
        'index' => 'guest',
        'profile' => 'guest',
        'login' => 'guest',
      ),
      ...and so forth for each controller and action (no other resources are included)
```

Here is the page layout template, default-layout.phtml showing the only javascript I use or pull in:

```
    <?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <?php echo $this->headTitle('TJLA Registration')->setSeparator(' - ')->setAutoEscape(false) ?>

        <?php echo $this->headMeta()
            ->appendName('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
            ->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge')
        ?>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <?php echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/tjla-tree.png'))
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/style.css')
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
         ?>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="masthead">
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container navbar-container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav'); ?>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
                <?php echo $this->content; ?>
                <hr>
                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y') ?> by Thomas Jefferson Leadership Academy. All rights reserved.</p>
                </footer>
            </div> <!-- /container -->

            <!-- Scripts -->
            <?php echo $this->inlineScript()
                ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js')
                ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
                ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
                ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5shiv.js',   'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',));
            ?>

            <script>
                $(function () {
                  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
                })
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What are acl-controls, and do they modify jQuery.prototype.button of Bootstrap?

Comment: Please include any JavaScript code associated with this as well.  Thanks

Comment: @NoBugs acl-controls restrict access to resources based on a user's role/permission level. In my case, permissions are granted or denied to each webpage and each action that can be taken from that page. They do not modify elements rendered on the page such as jQuery.prototype.button.

Comment: @Stanimir unfortunately, this is hosted on a site that does not give me access to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please excuse me for wasting your time. I discovered the problem; the page was overwritten with a previous version and the proper class was missing from the anchors. (role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary")

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct or delete your question.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` Check this link for more help on asking questions [help/on-topic]